# WPF app crashes on startup for one pc tested

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, exception, startup

I sent out copies of my app to several testers, and so far it works as expected on all except one of them. Since it was crashing on the startup I thought it would be on the InitializeComponent but it turns out its not. I have an unhandled exception handler that returns this:

[image]

I guess something is wrong with my BumpIntensity_Converter (IMultiValueConverter). I am passing in a double as a parameter to the converter, I don't know why that would be a problem. Here is line 21 (inside my converter), which is where the exception says it originates from:

```
double bump = double.Parse(((string) parameter));
```

Why would this be giving me an error? It works on all other machines tested, and this machine has nothing particularly special.

I tried replacing it with this:

```
double bump = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
```

but the results are the same.

Here is how I am using the converter in my xaml view:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BumpIntensity_Conv}" ConverterParameter="0.9">
    <Binding ElementName="LayerNormalThumbnail" Path="Width"/>
    <Binding ElementName="LayerNormalThumbnail" Path="Height"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: Are all the test PCs in the same language? If the culture info is different on the computers, then differences such as "." to "," will cause this exception.

Comment: Try InvariantCulture (or other cultures) in converting numerics

Comment: That might be it since this user is from Norway. InvariantCulture is foreign to me, I will look it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this user's PC is set up to parse doubles in European style.  In Europe, the use of the comma and period is reversed - the period is used as a thousands separator and the comma is the decimal separator.

Comment: I think you are right, the user is located in Norway. I replace my code with this: double.Parse(((string) parameter), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

I will post the results when he test's it.